# d3.js getBBox().width returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I'm creating a collapsible tree using D3.js.

I am appending image after text element to tree. When appending the image, I want to set width of node as x attribute of image element so that image gets append after the text element. I used getBBox() on it but it returns me {x:0, y:0, width:0, height:0}

Any suggestion on how to go about this?

The relevant code:

```
nodeEnter.append("text").attr("x", function (nodeData) { return nodeData.children || nodeData._children ? x_pos = -10 : x_pos = 10; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function (nodeData) { return nodeData.children || nodeData._children ? "end" : "start"; })
    .text(function (nodeData) { return nodeData.name; })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

nodeEnter.data(nodes).filter(function (nodeData) { return nodeData.icon ? nodeData.icon : null; }).append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (nodeData) { return nodeData.icon ? nodeData.icon : null; })
    .attr("x", , function (nodeData) { return d3.select(this.parentNode).node().getBBox().width; )
    .attr("y", "-7px")
    .attr("width", "16px")
    .attr("height", "14px");
```

Comment: have you tried looking at the log of : d3.select(this.parentNode).node().

Comment: Why not directly `this.parentNode.getBBox().width` ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy yes i did. It returns me this:                                                <g class="node" transform="translate(0,380)">    <circle r="0.000001" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle>               <text x="10" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1e-06;">DD, Number</text>                                                      <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/images/pk2.png" x="0px" y="-7px" width="16px" height="14px"></image></g>

Comment: @tarulen I have even tried your suggestion. It too returns 0.

Comment: try the parent of that parent. Looks like youre appending to nodeEnter which is appended to the container of the node. Try that

Comment: @thatOneGuy I tried parent of that parent. But still it returns 0.

Comment: I even tried to get text using d3.selectAll('text') and then get the width. But still no result. @thatOneGuy

Comment: you're going to have to post more code or event better get a JSFiddle together so we can see it

Comment: @thatOneGuy Here is a jsFiddle. Code is working fine as required but not in my application.  https://jsfiddle.net/Pkbond/dnwaabdw/

Comment: can you log this.parentNode  ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy yes. It returns me this: <g class="node" transform="translate(540,48)"><circle r="4.5" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle><text x="10" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;">BB, Number</text><image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/images/pk2.png" x="0px" y="-7px" width="16px" height="14px"></image></g>

Comment: i really don't see what your problem is. It works on jsfiddle so perhaps you need to step through your local data and compare